# Connecting to Oracle DB (on VMware ) using VS 2008?

Tags: oracle, ado.net, virtual-machine

**OBJECTIVE:Developing C# ADO.NET apps on Win7 with Oracle 10g running on XP in a VM**

i am trying to connect to oracle DB running on VMware workstation XP from Visual Studio 2008 but the connection is not successful when checked in Data>Add New Data Source in Visual Studio

-In VMware
Tried NAT,Bridged Mode.I am able to ping ips from host and vm.Firewall on XP and 7 are turned off

-In Oracle 10g running on Windows XP SP2
hostname is "vmxp1" when checked with "UTL_INADDR.get_host_name"

Is there any configurations i have to make on Oracle or XP . i am using the scott/tiger as pwd.

i am also not able to access iSQL*plus from VM or Win7 when using appropriate IPs

How will i connect to Oracle DB from Win7?>>a little search revealed Oracle client but i am confused between sql* plus client,instant client,oracle client. are these different products.

Comment: I suppose your Windows 7 system just doesn't know your WinXP by name. Try to use an IP address.

Comment: tried i am able to ping "ping vmxp1" from Win7

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly configured the tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora config files? They should be in a subdirectory of the oracle folder.

Also go to the data sources manager, in control panel, and add an Oracle 10g data source with the appropriate service name for the database. This service name is a feature of, and is determined by, the database. (The very same service name should be stored in your tnsnames.ora config file. This file will map the service name to the connect settings.)

If the Oracle 10g client is on your Windows XP VM then you should be using the VM. (You should do all of the above on your VM.)

Answer (score 0):

```
GLOBALDB =   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.17.132)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = globaldb)
    )   )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )   )
```